Per partes formula for integration with respect to finite measures on [0,1]
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite measures on $[0, 1]$, and define for $x \in [0, 1]$ the functions $F(x) = \mu([0, x])$ and $G(x) = \nu([0, x])$.
I want to show that the integration by parts formula of the form holds:
$$ \int_{[0,1]} F(x) \, \nu(dx) = F(1)G(1) - \int_{[0,1]} G(x) \, \mu(dx) + \int_{[0,1]} \mu(\{x\}) \, \nu(dx). $$
I know that from measure theory the following formula holds
$$
\int_{[0,1]} f(x) dg(x) = f(x) g(x) |_{[0,1]} - \int_{[0,1]} g(x) d f(x),
$$
I tried to prove the sought for equality by separating measures into continuous part and jumps (because $F$ and $G$ should, in my opinion, be nondecreasing and right continuous) and then adding the results, but I am not sure this way of proceeding is correct.
Edit: Actually, I don’t think anymore that the general per partes formula would be helpful here. I had an idea to integrate over a triangle (between 0 and 1) with rsepect to product measure and then use Fubini. Can someone help me with that?
I would very much apreciate any help and suggestions.

Are you assuming that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are defined on the same collection of measurable sets, or may they have measurable sets that are not measurable by the other?

@PaulSinclair I am assuming that they are defined on the same collection of measurable sets.

@PaulSinclair I edited the question a bit, giving an idea with product measures. Fubini gives us the first three terms, but I do not understand where the last term comes from. I guess it is because of the jumps but I do not know explicitly how to write it.

The last term appears to be picking up discrete contributions from $\mu$ and $\nu$. For absolutely continuous $\mu$, we would have $\mu({x}) = 0$ for all $x$ and the term would be $0$. Likewise, if $\mu({a}) > 0$ and $\nu(N_a) \to 0$ as $N_a \to {a}$ for some ${a}$ with neighborhoods $N_a$, then $a$ would not contribute to the last term. It is only non-zero when there are $a$ with $\mu(a) > 0, \nu(a) > 0$ (of which there can be at most a countable number of examples).

@PaulSinclair Thank you, I understand that but how could we explcitly add it in the proof? Like where would it appear? Because in my calculations with fubini I get The first two terms together and then the term on the left if I go by Fubini, but the last term never appears.
